# Rename file using regex (Linux Command line)

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I have a backup script which is creating two files:

**a**) db_mywebsite_2018-01-10_00-25.sql.gz

**b**) mywebsite1_2018-01-10_00-01.tar.gz

I'm looking for a Linux command with regex to rename both files to match
db_mywebsite.sql.gz
mywebsite1.tar.gz

The regex command need to remove date (20XX-XX-XX_XX-XX) from file names (each day it will be different).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Take a look at the `rename` command. It allows you to provide a perl-style `s/old/new/` expression to match a regexp and produce the new name from it.

Comment: please read your question once more see if it makes any sense. If it doesn't please reword the question at the earliest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are in your current directory you can use:

```
rename 's/(db_)?(mywebsite([0-9]+)?)_.+\.(tar|sql)\.gz/$1$2.$4.gz/g' *
```

Where:

- `(db_)?` check for 0 or 1 occurences of `db_`, stored in captured group 1
- `(mywebsite([0-9]+)?)` is a capture group for `mywebsite` following by any number of digits, saved as capture group 2
- `_.+` rather than search directly for a date this searches for `_` followed by any sequence of characters.
- `\.(tar|sql)\.gz` allows for either `.tar.gz` or `.sql.gz` and saves the 3 character sequence in capture group 4.
- The output combines capture groups 1, 2 and 4.

If the use of any sequence of characters after capture group to causes issues you can either be super strict with the date format:

```
rename 's/(db_)?(mywebsite([0-9]+)?)_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.(tar|sql)\.gz/$1$2.$4.gz/g' *
```

Or search for a combination of numbers, hyphens and underscores:

```
(db_)?(mywebsite([0-9]+)?)[0-9_-]+\.(tar|sql)\.gz
```